# JavaScript Function To Trigger CSS3 Transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, transition

Hi i am having problems with a `transition` of mine that gets called when a button is pressed. The reason i am confused is because it worked before but then i moved it onto a different `div` and now its not? when i mean its not working i mean that the function works (as in it does do something) and then runs the callback but when it switches the class' it doesn't 'animate' it. The `div` just stays there till the animation time is over and then runs the callback which hides it.

So basically it just hides it but doesn't animate the slide out effect that it should do.

the rest of the `switchClass` functions work fine even the one which makes the page slide back in.

The Code That Isn't Functioning Properly:

```
function hidepage() {
        $( ".PageShow" ).switchClass("PageShow", "PageHide", loadpanel);
// Alternative $( "PageContainer" ).switchClass("PageShow", "PageHide", loadpanel);
    };
```

And the rest of the code that goes with it...

CSS:

```
#PageContainer {
   margin-top:120px;
   width:100%;
}

.PageShow {
   position:fixed;
   -webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);
   -moz-transform:translate(0px,0px);
   -ms-transform:translate(0px,0px);
   -o-transform:translate(0px,0px);
   transform:translate(0px,0px);
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.PageHide {
   position:fixed;
   -webkit-transform:translate(-100%,0px);
   -moz-transform:translate(-100%,0px);
   -ms-transform:translate(-100%,0px);
   -o-transform:translate(-100%,0px);
   transform:translate(-100%,0px);
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: This code does work. But i will leave it up and let you know that if you are having the same problem as me it is most likely that you have some conflicting code or that you need some delays or something along those lines. I haven't been able to work out why it isn't working correctly but if you do please post it on here :) 
Thanks a lot,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your method `.switchClass()` to `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` it will work. Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/QyY9N/). There are two functions one is called `.hidepage()` which is the one with `.removeClass` and `.addClass` and the second function is `.hidepagetwo()` which uses `.switchClass()`

The real mistake is: there is a `});` missing at the end, at least in jsFiddle you code works after adding this.

Comment: I can see this working but i really want to use the switchClass... I mean it should work.

Comment: i have edited my original question so you can see more of the JavaScript code

Comment: and I complete the jsFiddle to have a function that uses `.switchClass()`

Comment: that's the same as my code though? and that's what my code used to do but now it doesn't give that nice slide effect? I really don't have a clue what is causing it to not run the effect like it used to :(

Comment: you added the javascript and the css of the jQuery UI? and it is not the same as your code, you are missing 2 parameters

Comment: yea i have and it is.. you don't need those parameters... i have removed them from your example and it still worked

Comment: look at the jsFiddle now, I'm using your code and it works just add `});` to the end of the jQuery code.

Comment: yea i do have that in my actual code :/ Its okay though i have just worked around it by putting it back onto my original div tag. I don't know why it wont work on the other div but I'm guessing its to do with conflicting code somewhere :) Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: oh also i forgot to mention that even using the .removeClass/.addClass it still didn't animate it. So it must be something messed up

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using switchClass incorrectly. Here is the API doc:

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Note that the method takes 2 mandatory params and 3 optional. You can't stuff loadpanel(if that's your callback function) into the 3rd param because it belongs in the 5th. You need to specify values for the 3rd and 4th in this case so your callback function ends up where it's expected.

Also, You have a lot of CSS transition stuff going on, but my understanding is that switchClass does a javascript animation between your two classes. Look how the example is at the above link. You just need to specify the before style in one class and the after style in another. switchClass will interpolate the in-between and do the animation without all the CSS transitions.

Since you have all those CSS animations in place on classes, another approach is to try jQuery's toggleClass which simply turns on/off the classes: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: you can do that because it recognizes that its the call back function. i am using it on all my other functions and its working fine. but for some reason its not switching the class correctly for this one. when i click the button it does take the correct amount of time before it uses the callback function which works correctly. its as if its switching the class's but not showing that it is.

Comment: i have edited my original question so you can see more of the JavaScript code

Comment: I just re-read your answer and i just realized how much of a Muppet i am :L I completely forgot that JQuery animates it automatically -_- but in any case it should still work how it is...